# Background doesn't show by chrome extension link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

I get an URL of image in extension:

```
var imgURL = chrome.extension.getURL("icons/16x16.png");
```

Then insert it like a style in element:

```
$(titleTag,value).first().prepend('<span class="goodSite" style="background-image: url('+imgURL+')"></span>');
```

But the background doesn't not show. In devmode I can see the link of background:

```
background-image: url(chrome-extension://phkehpgmmmdbkeeigmnnlceoloahchbd/icons/16x16.png);
```

and if I open it in new tab, I will see an image.

Comment: Does it work if you add quotes around the url? like `url('chrome-extension://...')`?

Comment: @tokoph When inspect element, style look like `style="background-image: url('chrome-extension://phkehpgmmmdbkeeigmnnlceoloahchbd/icons/16x16.png')"` There is no effect

Comment: See documentation for web_accessible_resources, declare your icon, reload the extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks a lot!